# Why C# output 0.0 for a simple Percentage formula?

Tags: c#

We find the percentage of a number by `(CurrentValue/Total)*100`. Now i apply this in `UpdateOverallProgress()`

```
private void UpdateOverallProgress()
 {
      var position = 20
      var count = 120
      Double percentage = (position / count * 100);
      progressOverall.Value = Convert.ToInt16(percentage);
 }
```

But no matter what the `position` is, the `percentage` is always `0.0`. Could anyone give me a hint what i'm doing wrong? I feel stupid...

Comment: Integer division strikes again. Plenty of answers are already available.

Comment: `position / count` => integer division `= 20 / 120 = 0`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sometimes I don't like the dupehammer. SO is for coding beginners, too. While the linked question explains the problem of integer division, there is no word about literals being interpreted as `int` and the valid answer to _this_ question that `var position = 20d` would solve the problem, too. Maybe OP already knew about integer division but not about those literals.

Comment: `Double percentage = (position * 100.0 / count);`

Comment: @harold, lol, i didn't know about parsing it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's because `var position` and `var count` are being treated as `int`, so the division is 0 unless position equals count.

Try changing them to a `double`.